# How to add multiple arrays from JSON into Google Sheets using Google Sheets app script

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I add the following fields:

1. weightTierInformation>name
2. weightTierInformation>gramAmount

To this code:

```
function test(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");

var options = {
     //"async": true,
     //"crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "clientId" : "1",
       "key": "1",
       "Prefer": "code=200",
       "Prefer":"dynamic=true"
       
       }}




  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/locations/1/inventory",options).getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);




var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId,cannabinoidInformation }) =>  cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name}) => [productId,lowerRange,name])
);



targetsheet.getRange(2, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

}
```

At the moment the output populate A-C columns, I want to populate D-E with the subfields above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId,cannabinoidInformation }) =>  cannabinoidInformation.map(({lowerRange,name}) => [productId,lowerRange,name])
```

);

#### To:

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ productId, cannabinoidInformation, weightTierInformation }) => cannabinoidInformation.map(({ lowerRange, name }, i) => [productId, lowerRange, name, weightTierInformation[i].name, weightTierInformation[i].gramAmount]));
```

- By this, modification, the values of `productId`, `cannabinoidInformation`, `weightTierInformation` are put to the column "A", the columns "B" to "C", the columns "D" to "E".

Comment: AMAZING as always! I do have one more question, I tried to replace your medication on another API (that doesn't have a mock server so I can't share the keys here) but when I write it like this:

`itemsInCart[i].quantity` 

I get this error: **Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity')**

But if I write it like this:
`itemsInCart[i]`

I don't get an error (but I get all the JSON array into one cell)

Can you please tell me how to fix this error? @Tanaike

Comment: @Kal El Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I do have one more question, I tried to replace your medication on another API (that doesn't have a mock server so I can't share the keys here) but when I write it like this:`, I would like to support you. But, in this case, please post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?